# How do I verify a file's existence in iCloud?

Tags: objective-c, file, icloud, nsfilemanager

I know that the file exists, because I can download it, but I need to check to see whether it exists.  I have tried using

```
[NSFileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:]
```

but it gives me null.  I don't understand why that is because I can still download the files that I'm looking for.  Maybe it's an incorrect URL, but the URL that I'm using is the one that I printed at creation of my UIDocument that I'm looking for.  Maybe I'm using the wrong method?

EDIT:

I have also tried using NSMetadataQuery, and I can get it to give back notifications, but it doesn't ever have results even though I can explicitly download the files I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5):

To find files in iCloud, you use `NSMetadataQuery`. That will find both files that have already been downloaded as well as files that are in the user's account but which haven't been downloaded to the local device yet. Using `NSFileManager` will, at best, only find files that have already been downloaded.

You set it up with something like this:

```
NSMetadataQuery *query = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
[self setMetadataQuery:query];
[query setSearchScopes:@[NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDataScope]];
[query setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K LIKE '*'", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey]];
```

You'll want to observe `NSMetadataQueryDidStartGatheringNotification`, `NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification`, and probably `NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification`. Then start the query:

```
[query startQuery];
```

With that done, you'll get notifications as the query discovers iCloud files. The notifications will include instances of `NSMetadataItem`, which you can use to get information like file size, download status, etc.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not working for me either.  The reason I asked this question is because I can't get NSMetadataQuery to work, and I want to make sure that the files I'm looking for are in the place I think they are (I logged the fileURL of my UIDocument).

Comment: `NSMetadatqQuery` is how you do it. If you can't get it to work, post a question about getting it to work. That's the API, and if you're using it correctly but getting no results, either (a) the file's not there, or (b) iCloud is screwed up in a way that you can't fix.

Answer (score 2):

Use a metadata query - here is some sample code

```
/*!  Creates and starts a metadata query for iCloud files

 */
- (void)createFileQuery {
    [_query stopQuery];

        if (_query) {
            [_query startQuery];
        }
        else {
            _query = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];

            [_query setSearchScopes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope, NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDataScope, nil]];
            // NSString * str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"*.%@",_fileExtension];
            NSString *str = @"*";
            [_query setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K LIKE %@", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey, str]];

            NSNotificationCenter* notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
            [notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(fileListReceived) name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification object:_query];
            [notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(fileListReceived) name:NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification object:_query];
            [_query startQuery];
        }

}

/*! Gets called by the metadata query any time files change.  We need to be able to flag files that
 we have created so as to not think it has been deleted from iCloud.

 */
- (void)fileListReceived {
    LOG(@"fileListReceived called.");

    NSArray* results = [[_query results] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSMetadataItem* firstObject, NSMetadataItem* secondObject) {
        NSString* firstFileName = [firstObject valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemFSNameKey];
        NSString* secondFileName = [secondObject valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemFSNameKey];
        NSComparisonResult result = [firstFileName.pathExtension compare:secondFileName.pathExtension];
        return result == NSOrderedSame ? [firstFileName compare:secondFileName] : result;
    }];

    //FLOG(@" results of query are %@", results);
    for (NSMetadataItem* result in results) {
        NSURL* fileURL = [result valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemURLKey];
        NSString* fileName = [result valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemDisplayNameKey];
        NSNumber* percentDownloaded = [result valueForAttribute:NSMetadataUbiquitousItemPercentDownloadedKey];
        NSNumber *isDownloaded = nil;
        NSNumber *isDownloading = nil;
        NSError *er;
        [fileURL getResourceValue: &isDownloaded forKey:NSURLUbiquitousItemIsDownloadedKey error:&er];
        [fileURL getResourceValue: &isDownloading forKey:NSURLUbiquitousItemIsDownloadingKey error:&er];
        FLOG(@" Found file %@", fileName);
   }

}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesigningForDocumentsIniCloud.html):

> In iOS, actively download files when required. Items in iCloud but not
>   yet local are not automatically downloaded by iOS; only their metadata
>   is automatically downloaded. The initial download of new iCloud-based
>   documents requires your attention and careful design in your app.
>   After you explicitly download such an item, the system takes care of
>   downloading changes arriving from iCloud.
>
> Consider keeping track of
>   file download status as part of your iOS app’s model layer. Having
>   this information lets you provide a better user experience: you can
>   design your app to not surprise users with long delays when they want
>   to open a document that is not yet local. For each file (or file
>   package) URL provided by your app’s metadata query, get the value of
>   the `NSURLUbiquitousItemIsDownloadedKey`key by calling the `NSURL` method
>   `getResourceValue:forKey:error:`. Reading a file that has not been
>   downloaded can take a long time, because the coordinated read
>   operation blocks until the file finishes downloading (or fails to
>   download).
>
> For a file (or file package) that is not yet local, you can initiate
>   download either when, or before, the user requests it. If your app’s
>   user files are not large or great in number, one strategy to consider
>   is to actively download all the files indicated by your metadata
>   query. For each file (or file package) URL provided by the query, make
>   the corresponding item local by calling the `NSFileManager` method
>   `startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL:error:`. If you pass this method a
>   URL for an item that is already local, the method performs no work and
>   returns YES.

Update: iOS7 should use `NSURLUbiquitousItemDownloadingStatusKey` instead of `NSURLUbiquitousItemIsDownloadedKey`.