# How to check NSDocument is exist on iCloud or not

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud

I have used the following code to check that the file exist or not, but the NSMetaDataquery is giving me a count zero.

```
-(void)loadData:(NSMetadataQuery *)query
{
    NSLog(@"Count %d", [query resultCount]);
    if([query resultCount] == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"File Not Exists");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"File Exists");
    }
}
```

Is their any other way to check the file exist on iCloud?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21094534/how-do-i-verify-a-files-existence-in-icloud